# How to check if Monkeyrunner's waitForConnection() failed

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

I'd like to be able to determine when a call to Monkeyrunner's waitForConnection() method fails (times out). It seems that even when the device isn't present and the method times out the same object is returned. I was looking through the API to possibly use a different method to figure out if the phone wasn't connected or not, but nothing has worked so far. Any advice?

PS. This is being done inside a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into similar problem before.
This may be updated in ICS SDK but as of now, you can use below mentioned solution.

```
try:
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(20)
    strProperty = device.getProperty('model')
except:
    device = None
```

This is a workaround with less possible code.
Thank You.